# To prove: The intersection of all normal subgroups of finite index of a free group is trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, free-groups

Let $S$ be a set, $G$ its [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) and $\mathcal{N}$ the set of normal 
$N  \leq G$ such that $[G:N] < \infty$. Prove that 
$$
\bigcap_{N \in \mathcal{N}} N \ = \ \{ e\}
$$

---

I know how free groups are constructed and defined, aside from that I know very little about them. I don't have much knowledge about covering spaces either, even though that theory is frequently used when dealing with free groups.

Given $x \in G \setminus \{e\}$, is there any straight forward way to construct a normal subgroup $N$ of finite index such that $x \notin N$? I know that this $N$ has to be free as well, but I really don't know what generators I have to choose. I hope you can help me.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem to attempt if you have only just started learning about free groups! There are some proofs here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20471